# Getting a random wiki article with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, api, random, wikipedia, wiki

I want to create a website where it takes a random wikipedia article and turns it into a mad lib. How would I use the Wikipedia API through JS to get a random article's summary?

I already tried this

```
const userAction = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary');
    const myJson = await response.json();
}
```

but it didn't return anything when I added `alert(myJson);` to see what it got.

Comment: try `alert(myJson.title);`, does it display the random article's title?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You don't see results because you are trying to pass whole JSON object to alert. If you would do `console.log(myJson)` you would see JSON in console. Or if you would pass some string property to the alert you would see that, like `alert(myJson.title)`